# Passing the return value of a function into a custom Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, angular-components

Is there anything wrong with passing a value into a custom component like this?  I noticed that when I console.log inside someFunction it is called many times when the component is loaded.  Can someone explain?

HTML

```
<custom-component [someInput]=“someFunction(‘someParameter’)></custom-component>
```

TS

```
someFunction(someParameter) {
    return someValue
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES, You are right,**

In `angular` you **should not** call `functions` in `template`.

**Reason**

The main goal of angular is, `Rendering` the `DOM` when detecting any changes. So If angular detect any `changes/updates` in your application, It will **re-render** the template. So when It **re-render** each time, The **function** you used in **template(props)** will be called.

> **Always follow the best practices**

[why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)

Comment: Good luck dude!

Comment: That thing is a common mistake when starting with Angular. +1 for the easy to digest and straight to the point answer.